# rosbag time slicing?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a tool for slicing a bag file by time (e.g. cut out 30m of data from the middle of a bag)? Or does everyone just use a filter over the timestamps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40898/rosbag-time-slicing?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about such a tool. With rxbag you can export parts of a bag file though. Another way would be to write a simple python script that uses the rosbag python API. Shouldn't be too much code and it should be pretty similar to the first example in the [rosbag cookbook](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-08-08**:
How do you export part of the bag with rxbag? That was my intuition as well, but I couldn't find the feature...

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-08**:
Mark a region on the timeline, above the marker for the current position, right-click and select 'copy region to bag'